# Nodejs - how to catch thrown error and format it?

Tags: node.js, koa2

I don't quite understand how to catch the error that I throw somewhere deep inside my routes, e.g.:

```
// put
router.put('/', async (ctx, next) => {
  let body = ctx.request.body || {}
  if (body._id === undefined) {
    // Throw the error.
    ctx.throw(400, '_id is required.')
  }
})
```

I will get when _id is not provided:

```
_id is required.
```

But I don't throw it like in **plain text**. I would prefer catching it at the **top level** and then formatting it, e.g.:

```
{
  status: 400.
  message: '_id is required.'
}
```

According to the [doc](https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki/Error-Handling):

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    try {
      await next()
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.status = err.status || 500

      console.log(ctx.status)
      ctx.body = err.message
      
      ctx.app.emit('error', err, ctx)
    }
  })
```

But even without that try catch in my middleware, I still get `_id is required.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an error with needed status code:

```
ctx.throw(400, '_id is required.');
```

And use [default error handler](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/error-handling.md#default-error-handler) to format the error response:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next();
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.status = err.statusCode || err.status || 500;
    ctx.body = {
      status: ctx.status,
      message: err.message
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks. `ctx.throw(400, '_id is required.')` is exactly what I do. I might did something wrong somewhere else!

Comment: Glad that my answer was helpful, the problem was is in default error handler, you assigned a string to `ctx.body` instead of object `{ status, message }`.